# Refactoring/Improving a basic JavaScript exercise -- turn a numeric score into a letter grade

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm about 10 hours into my programming career; bear with me please.

My attempt to solve the problem of creating a website with an HTML input area and button such that entering a number between 0 and 100 inclusive and clicking the button will take your score and return an alert box with whatever letter grade corresponds to that score is as follows:

First, the .js file

```
function grade() {
  score = document.form1.grade.value;
  if (score==100) {alert("Perfect score!");}
  else if (score>=90) {alert("You got an A");}
  else if (score>=80) {alert("You got a B");}
  else if (score>=70) {alert("You got a C");}
  else if (score>=60) {alert("You got a D");}
  else {alert("Failure.");}
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="number"
  name="grade"
  value=""
  min="0" max="100">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Grade" onclick="grade()">
```

I understand that this is at the level of being trivial, but just doing this simple exercise raised a ton of questions for me.

1. Why does the button not work if I put it within the form tags?
2. I tried for an unreasonably long time to get the js to work with `switch`. Is there a way to do it or am I doing it right with several `if/else if` statements?
3. When I didn't have `onsubmit="return false"` pressing enter in the text field basically borked everything, and `onsubmit="grade()" didn't work at all. Is there any way to make it so that when you enter a number (87) and press return it doesn't submit but executes the grade() function?
4. Any general structural improvements?

Comment: @Austin Yun: this is how you use switch for this scenario. http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/KcZPe/

Comment: @naveen: That's actually really clever, but if I'm right, it doesn't work if grade boundaries are irregular, i.e., 100..98 is an A, 97..84 is a B, 83..80 is a C.

Comment: yep. steps should be equal. just gave one because you asked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For compatibility reasons, `grade` is set to your `input` element, which is also named `grade`.
2. There is a way, but it would be quite verbose. `if` statements should be fine here.
3. Try `window.grade(); return false;`. The `window.grade` gets around the fact that plain `grade` is masked to the `input`.
4. You might want to learn about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). This lets you completely remove the snippets of JavaScript code (eg. `onclick="window.grade(); return false;"`) from the HTML, leading the HTML to be cleaner. You also may want to learn about [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) (which you'd use to replace `document.form1.grade`, which is a slightly old way of doing things).

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/twG6R/) using `addEventListener` and `getElementById`. Have fun learning to program!

Comment: Yep, definitely learn about `document.getElementById()` (and use of the `id` attribute in general.

Comment: Hm. Why does the function `grade` now take the parameter `event`?

Comment: @Austin: At the end of the function, it calls `event.preventDefault()`. That will prevent it from sending the form to the server, which you probably don't want if JavaScript is handling the event.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200291/icktoofay)'s fine (and accepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688608/refactoring-improving-a-basic-javascript-exercise-turn-a-numeric-score-into-a/6688671#6688671), `if`'s are just fine, but if you wanted to use a `switch` statement...

```
switch (true) {
  case score == 100: alert("Perfect score!"); break;
  case score >= 90:  alert("You got an A");   break;
  case score >= 80:  alert("You got a B");    break;
  case score >= 70:  alert("You got a C");    break;
  case score >= 60:  alert("You got a D");    break;
  default:           alert("Failure.");       break;
}
```

Comment: `switch (true)`? Is that used because the variable `score` is assigned beforehand?

Comment: `switch(value)` takes whatever value is in the brackets and looks for the first `case` that matches. So if your switching value is the simple boolean `true` it will match it to the first `case` with an expression that evaluates to true. If none match it uses the `default`. Perfectly valid JavaScript, but kind of non-standard for switches in general (several other languages that do have switch don't support that usage). It is much more "normal" to switch on a value that is a variable matching to cases that have constants.

Comment: Actually has nothing to do with the variable `score`, specifically.  `switch(true)` means run the first case that returns true.  So the order here is important.  This works exactly like the if/elseif/else, although in my personal opinion is easier to read at a glance.

Comment: OK, because the very first way I tried to implement this was with a function `grade(score)` containing inside it `switch (score) { case score == 100:` etc. I see where the mistake was made now -- `switch (score) { case 100: .....` would work, but that's not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `switch` versus a set of `if / else if / else`: in most programming languages `switch` is intended only to match on specific values, not to match on comparisons like the greater-thans you need for your grade calculation. In JavaScript there is a way to get around that and use comparisons within the `switch` but I don't recommend it because the `if / else if` structure is already perfectly suited to that. So yes, you are doing it right.

Regarding structure, one way to make your code a little bit more flexible would be to have your function return a string that is the grade result instead of displaying it directly with `alert()`. That way if you later decide you want to do something else with that string instead of alerting it you don't have to change the core function. Also, I'd change it to take the score in as a parameter rather than always just calculating a grade for a specific score field.

Some examples of what I'm talking about are in the following code, noting that this isn't necessarily very good code but since you're so new I don't want to confuse things by introducing too many concepts all at once. Still, it includes some basic function parameter and string concatenation stuff. Let me know if you need an explanation of any of this.

```
<script>

function calculateGrade(score) {
  if (score==100) { return "Perfect score!"; }
  else if (score>=90) { return "You got an A"; }
  else if (score>=80) { return "You got a B"; }
  else if (score>=70) { return "You got a C"; }
  else if (score>=60) { return "You got a D"; }
  else { return "Failure."; }
}

function alertGrade(elementId) {
  var score = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
  var grade = calculateGrade(score);
  alert("Score of " + score + ": " + grade);
}

function displayResult() {
  // an example that calculateGrade's return directly instead
  // of storing it in a local variable
  document.getElementById('result').value = "1: "
                  + calculateGrade(document.getElementById('score1').value)
                  + "   2: "
                  + calculateGrade(document.getElementById('score2').value);
}

</script>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="return false;">
  Score 1: <input type="number" id="score1" name="score" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="button" value="Alert Grade 1" onclick="alertGrade('score1')">
  <br/>
  Score 2: <input type="number" id="score2" name="score" min="0" max="100">
  <input type="button" value="Alert Grade 2" onclick="alertGrade('score2')">

  <input type="button" value="Display Both Results" onclick="displayResult()">
  <input type="text" id="result" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Either the `displayResult()` function or the button that calls it is not working for me. It returns `1: Failure 2: Failure` no matter what input is given. [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/twG6R/5/)

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in that function. I had said `calculateGrade(document.getElementById('score1'))` when I should have said `calculateGrade(document.getElementById('score1').value)` (I had left off the `.value` - and same for score2). I've edited my post to fix that. I take it then that the other buttons/functions worked? (I didn't test it before posting, obviously.)

Comment: Yes, it works after appending .value. However, after separating the calculating and alerting (which seems like a good idea), I can't get it to work with a submit event listener. I believe it has something to do with the fact that in the solution icktoofay showed, `grade()` is changed to `grade(event)`, but I don't know what exactly the event parameter is doing, so nothing is getting displayed, and the submit isn't being interrupted either. I'd be curious to see how you would do it with no consideration for introducing too many new concepts. [eventlistener attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/twG6R/6/