# Syntax error in Javascript converting #s to letters

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javaScript program turning #s into grades.  I keep getting a syntax    error but I can't seem to see it.  Do you have a suggestions for me to fix this?

```
<script>        

            if (var entry >=94 and (&&) var entry <=100) prompt var      letterGrade="A";
            else if (var entry >=86 and (&&) var entry <=93 ) prompt var letterGrade ="B";
            else if (var entry >=78 and (&&) var entry <=85) prompt var letterGrade ="C";
            else if (var entry >=70 and (&&) var entry <=77 ) prompt var letterGrade ="D";
            else if (var entry >=69) prompt var letterGrade ="F";


        alert("Number grade = " + entry + "\n"
                + "Letter grade = " + letterGrade);
    }
    while (entry != 999);
</script>
```

Comment: I would first start with becoming more familiar with JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Remove all those `var` keywords. The would need to be a the [beginning of a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Also, use plain `&&` instead of `and`, and I'm not sure what that `prompt` thingy is supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps use http://www.jslint.com/ and read a book about Javascript.

Comment: This could be useful : http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/syntax-diagrams.html

Comment: http://bit.ly/18K47CU

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do* with that...pseudo-code?

Comment: Have a look at http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Comment: the entire section is basically a syntax error. I see what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688608/refactoring-improving-a-basic-javascript-exercise-turn-a-numeric-score-into-a

Comment: I don't get trashing the user for posting code with newbie mistakes; *all* of use were there ourselves at one time.  So just answer his/her question (I did below), or provide a helpful reference site, or *something* constructive. Unwelcoming is as bad as unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

okay, lets see.

```
<script>        

        if (var entry >=94 and (&&) var entry <=100) prompt var      letterGrade="A";
```

`and (&&)` is very odd. Where did you get that from? You mean `&&` probably.
`prompt` doesn't mean anything in this code snippet. The way it's just hanging out there before `var` is a syntax error. Is it supposed to be a function?
`var letterGrade="A";` is actually correct. You're assigning a variable.

when you're trying to compare the variable to the number, you're using `var`... this is ONLY for assigning variables. You're actually clearing it right there and setting it to `undefined` instead of referring to it.

```
        else if (var entry >=86 and (&&) var entry <=93 ) prompt var letterGrade ="B";
        else if (var entry >=78 and (&&) var entry <=85) prompt var letterGrade ="C";
        else if (var entry >=70 and (&&) var entry <=77 ) prompt var letterGrade ="D";
        else if (var entry >=69) prompt var letterGrade ="F";
```

All of these share the same issues with the above statement.

```
    alert("Number grade = " + entry + "\n"
            + "Letter grade = " + letterGrade);
```

That would work.

```
}
```

This random brace is a syntax error.

```
while (entry != 999);
```

what is this `while` supposed to do? This would be an infinite loop. There is nothing in the body. Isn't `entry` also supposed to be a percent grade? What does 999 have to do with anything?

```
</script>
```

So, let's see. This does what your code seems to intend.

```
var letterGrade; //declare the variable
var entry=87; //for testing... otherwise we'd get an referenceError

if(entry>94){ letterGrade='A'; }
else if(entry>86){ letterGrade='B'; }
else if (entry>78){ letterGrade='C'; }
else if (entry>70){ letterGrade='D'; }
else { letterGrade='F'; }


alert("Number grade = " + entry + "\n" + "Letter grade = " + letterGrade);
```

There are more elegant ways to do this, but hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those "var" keywords. Also, the range specification it a bit tedious. I would recommend you create a simple function to get the grade.  Here's some JavaScript you can put in the body of the document to demo...

```
function GetGrade(v)
{
    if (v > 100) return "n/a";
    if (v <69) return "F";
    if (v <77) return "D";
    if (v <85) return "C";
    if (v <93) return "B";
    return "A";
}
// Now let's show some sample scores and grades...
var grades =[94,91,88,72];
for(var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
{
    document.writeln('<p>Number grade ' +  grades[i] + ' = Letter grade: ' + GetGrade(grades[i]) + '</p>');
}
```